# Empty cdkDropList container "lose drop area" if its position changes

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular-cdk

**Reproduction**

Hi, i've found some weird issue using a simple empty div as "drop container" in order to show users a box where to drop contents into.
It seems that if this box, for whatever reason, changes its visibility, position, etc... it loses the "drop capability".

Here's the stackblitz used to reproduce the bug:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqxu2m

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Test the example dragging a "done" element into the "to do" list (a "exited" console log should appear each time you enter the "to do" container while dragging an element)
2. In the template file, uncomment the second line (as suggested by the comment) and retry the step 1, now it's impossibile to make the console log"exited" again

**Expected Behavior**

The drop zone of the container should be always active

**Actual Behavior**

The drop zone of the container is lost whenever the container is moved around or it's visibility changes

**Environment**

Angular: 8.2.14

CDK/Material: 8.2.3

Chrome: 78.0.3904.97

Operating System : Windows

Comment: Does anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

```
(cdkDropListExited)="log($event)"
```

should be on `cdkDrag` element, as it is a `ckdDrag` function.

See https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api for reference.